# Calculating the number of occasions with a set period sumproduct function

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

```
=SUMPRODUCT((F16:F274=("A"))  *(F17:F275<>("A")))
+SUMPRODUCT((F16:F274=("AH")) *(F17:F275<>("AH")))
+SUMPRODUCT((F16:F274=("AU")) *(F17:F275<>("AU")))
+SUMPRODUCT((F16:F274=("AHU"))*(F17:F275<>("AHU")))
```

I am using the above formula to add the number of occasions sickness occurs using the following as a key. It works fine until you get say an A and a AH in the same sickness period.

Instead of reporting just one occasion off it reports two. Is there a way I can separate this?

```
Absence A
Absence 1/2 AH
Absence Unpaid  AU
Absence 1/2 Unpaid  AHU
```

Comment: Please give a better explanation of what your data mean, what you are trying to accomplish, and what result you want to get.

Comment: Hi Scott I am trying to calculate the Brandford Factor for HR and want the formula to return the individual number of grouped period of absence regardless of which denominations of the folowing the period contains Absence A
Absence 1/2 AH
Absence Unpaid  AU
Absence 1/2 Unpaid  AHU currently I can only get it to work if each period only contains on type of absence. I trust this is clearer

Comment: @user158056: In the future, if you clarify a question, consider doing it by _editing the question_ – see [the **How do I ask questions here?** section](http://superuser.com/faq#howtoask) of the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not 100% sure that I understand the question, but if none of your non-absence codes begin with "A", then

```
=COUNTIFS(F16:F274, "=A*", F17:F275, "<>A*")
```

might be what you want.

Comment: @pnuts: That seems to be what user158056 wants.  From the question: “I am using the above formula …  It works fine until you get, say, an ‘A’ and an ‘AH’ in the same sickness period.  (\n)  Instead of reporting just one occasion off it reports two.”  And from the comment: “I … want the formula to return the individual number of grouped periods of absence regardless of which denominations … the period contains”.

Comment: @pnuts: OK, this time _I_ misunderstood _your_ comment.  No, my formula is **not** (almost) always going to give the answer 1.  For example, if F16:F20 contain { ‘A’, ‘P’, ‘A’, ‘P’, ‘A’ }, my formula evaluates to 3.

Comment: Thank you both and I like the humour. I am sory that I did not explain in a better way. You are correct it is the Bradford Factor.People from Brandford cant type as you can tell.What I am trying to do is to allow staff to enter various type's of absence Absence A
Absence 1/2 AH
Absence Unpaid  AU
Absence 1/2 Unpaid  AHU

Comment: Thanks for responding.  But rather than repeating what you’ve already said, please describe how your data are structured.  For example, are they (the rows) structured as { 23-Jul, ‘P’ }, { 24-Jul, ‘P’ }, { 25-Jul, ‘A’ }, { 26-Jul, ‘A’ }, { 27-Jul, ‘P’ }, { 30-Jul, ‘P’ }, { 31-Jul, ‘P’ }, { 1-Aug, ‘P’ }, { 2-Aug, ‘P’ }, { 3-Aug, ‘AH’ }?  Or are they more like { 25-Jul, ‘A’, 2 }, { 3-Aug, ‘AH’, 1 }?  And explain what result you want to get from the formula.

Comment: @user158056: By the way, when you answer somebody’s question (from a comment) in a new comment, it’s conventional to mention that person’s name, preceded by “@”, as in “@Scott, @pnuts”.  That way we get notified.  See the **Replying in comments** paragraphs of [the **Comment formatting** section](http://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) of the Markdown Editing Help page.